# Xcode 9 - Simulator - Hide Title Bar

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode9

In Xcode 9, I haven't found a way yet to disable the title bar when the bezel is turned off. I'm trying to make the simulator go full screen for a demo on a touchscreen TV and the little gray bar at the top is preventing it from getting there. I've tried many different things from changing plist items to trying to add code for NStitlebar but to no avail. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

This is what I see: 
[Simulator Image with Title Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU0ID.jpg)

This is what I want to see: 
[Mockup removing the title bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38zCp.jpg)

Comment: Strongly related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/197606/90404 IMO your best bet is Accessibility Zoom.

Answer (score -1):

So the best way I've found in my research is to do it not in the code of the app but through the hidden Internal menu option of Simulator. Apple has placed a hidden Internal menu with additional features that can only be enable through some Terminal commands.

Link here to a simple tutorial: http://www.cansurmeli.com/blog/enabling-hidden-xcode-simulator-features/

Once that is enabled, then turn the "Allow Fullscreen Mode" in the Internal menu as well as change the options in "Floating Name" to remove the bar and expand fully.

Comment: The provided URL /blog/enabling-hidden-xcode-simulator-features/ was not found on the server.